# SVN Reporting on changed files

Tags: svn

Our setup:

Trunk (holds production code)
Releases (holds branches where we do our builds)
   Release1
   Release2
   Release3
Branches (holds a branch for each work request)
   WR1
   WR2
   WR3

When we do a release, we will merge several of the work requests branches into one of the release request branches.

My question is how can I run a report on the release branch that will give me the output of the files changed from when the release branch was created and which WR number they came from?

Many thanks